# Найти элемент массива в строке

Tags: javascript

Как проверить содержится элемент массива в строке или нет?

### Пример:

```
  function f1() 
  var n,p;
  n = document.getElementById('num1').value;//строка которая вводится пользователем
  p = document.getElementById('out');

  var ru = ["run", "went", "go", "ran"];

  if (n==какой либо строке из массива ru) {
    p.innerHTML = 'Верно';
  } else {
    p.innerHTML = 'Неверно';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё так можно.

```js
let list = ['here', 'there', 'yes', 'no'];
document.getElementById('num').addEventListener('input', function(){
  let p = document.getElementById('out');
  
  for(const val of list) {
    if(this.value === val) {
      p.innerHTML = 'OK';
      break;
      console.log('OK');
    }
    else {
      p.innerHTML = 'FALSE';
      console.log('FALSE');
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num">
<p id="out"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод массива `indexOf` который возвращает номер позиции при совпадение, или `-1` при отсутствии. Чтобы не сравнивать выражение с `-1` можно к нему применить побитовое отрицание `~`, которое для `-1` вернет `0`, для `-2` вернет `-1`, и тд

```js
const a = 'num1'
const b = 'nam2'
const ru = ['num1', 'num2','num3']
console.log(Boolean(~ru.indexOf(a)))
console.log(Boolean(~ru.indexOf(b)))
```